# Does there exist a Latin square of order 9 for which its 9 broken diagonals and 9 broken antidiagonals are transversals?

Tags: co.combinatorics, latin-square

A Latin square of order $n$ has $n$ broken diagonals and $n$ broken antidiagonals.  When $n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$, we have *diagonally cyclic Latin squares* in which those $2n$ diagonals are transversals (i.e., every symbol occurs exactly once).  For example

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & \color{red} 3 & 2 & 1 & \color{blue} 0 \\
1 & 0 & \color{red} 4 & \color{blue} 3 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{red} 0 & 4 \\
0 & \color{blue} 4 & 3 & 2 & \color{red} 1 \\
\color{purple} 2 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I highlight a broken diagonal in red and a broken antidiagonal in blue (which overlap in the purple entry).

We see that symbols in rows differ by $1$, symbols in columns differ by $2$, symbols along broken diagonals differ by $1$ and symbols along broken antidiagonals differ by $3$.  Since these are all generators of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we have a Latin square with transversals along its $5$ broken diagonals and $5$ broken antidiagonals.  The same thing works whenever $1,2,3$ are all generators $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which is when $n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$.

A Latin square satisfying this condition is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) to circulant and back-circulant Latin squares of its order (and, in fact, this is an equivalent condition), such as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for order $5$.  For even orders, Euler showed circulant (and back-circulant) Latin squares don't have transversals (let alone orthogonal mates), thus the desired Latin square is impossible when $n$ is even.

This leaves the $n \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ cases unresolved.  It's impossible when $n=3$ (proof by hand), so the next case is $n=9$.  Modifying the diagonally cyclic Latin square construction by replacing the first row with any other row doesn't work (assuming [my GAP code](https://pastebin.com/C72iAfeH) is correct).  However, there may be other ways to construct these.

**Question**: Does there exist a Latin square of order 9 for which its 9 broken diagonals and 9 broken antidiagonals are transversals?

My [brute-force GAP code](https://pastebin.com/NLBvBTir) is too slow for this problem, and it's probably not worth writing more efficient code without checking if the problem has already been resolved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've verified with ILP that such Latin squares do not exist for $n\in\{9,15,21,27\}$.

The ILP formulation is based on binary indicator variables $p_{c,i,j}$ telling whether Latin square has character $c$ at position $(i,j)$, with constraints
$$\begin{cases}
\sum_i p_{c,i,j} = 1, \\
\sum_j p_{c,i,j} = 1, \\
\sum_i p_{c,i,i+j} = 1, \\
\sum_i p_{c,i,j-i} = 1, \\
\sum_c p_{c,i,j} = 1,
\end{cases}$$
which ensure that each row/column/diagonal/antidiagonal contains each character, and that each position is occupied by a single character.

Comment: Excellent thanks!  It seems likely there is an underlying mathematical reason for this.

Answer (score 19):

Oh, I just realized how to prove non-existence for all $n \equiv 3 \pmod 6$.

We take the circulant and back-circulant Latin squares, defined as $L_{ij} = i+j \pmod n$ and $M_{ij} = i-j \pmod n$.  Suppose there is a third Latin square $X$ which is orthogonal to both of these Latin squares.  Choose a symbol, say $0$, and let $\{(r_i,c_i)\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ be the cells of $X$ containing $0$.

Then we know:

- $\{r_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} = \mathbb{Z}_n$,
- $\{c_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} = \mathbb{Z}_n$,
- $\{r_i+c_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} = \mathbb{Z}_n$ (because $X$ is orthogonal to $L$), and
- $\{r_i-c_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1} = \mathbb{Z}_n$ (because $X$ is orthogonal to $M$).

Now define the permutation $\sigma: \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $\sigma(c_i)=r_i$.  Then $\sigma$ is an example of a *strong complete mapping* of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, i.e., it's a permutation in which $i \mapsto \sigma(i)-i$ is a permutation, and $i \mapsto \sigma(i)+i$ is a permutation.

Next we hit the problem with this:

> *Theorem 15*. A finite abelian group admits strong complete mappings if and only if neither its Sylow 2-subgroup nor its Sylow 3-subgroup is nontrivial and cyclic.
> <sub>Anthony B. Evans, *The existence of strong complete mappings*, Electron. J. Combin ([pdf](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v19i1p34/pdf/)).</sub>

When $n \equiv 3 \pmod 6$, the Sylow 3-subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is nontrivial ($n$ is divisible by $3$) and cyclic (subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic), so $\sigma$ does not exist.

Comment: Elementary self-contained argument: the sum $S$ of squares of all $r_i+c_i$ and $r_i-c_i$ equals to $2(\sum r_i^2+c_i^2)$ which equals modulo $n$ to $4(1^2+\dots+n^2)$. On the other hand, $S$ must be equal modulo $n$ to $2 (1^2+\ldots+n^2) $. A contradiction, since $2 (1^2+\ldots+n^2)=n(n+1)(2n+1)/3$ is not divisible by $n$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Nice!  I tried making the "sum up the numbers" argument work, but didn't think to sum up the squares.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, pandiagonal Latin squares fail to exist unless the order lacks factors of $2$ or $3$. But odd multiples of $3$ do allow one of the two diagonal directions to be cyclic, along with the rows and columns.

3×3:

$\begin{matrix}
A&B&C\\B&C&A\\C&A&B\\\end{matrix}$

9×9:

$\begin{matrix}
A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I\\
E&F&G&H&I&A&B&C&D\\
I&A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H\\
D&E&F&G&H&I&A&B&C\\
H&I&A&B&C&D&E&F&G\\
C&D&E&F&G&H&I&A&B\\
G&H&I&A&B&C&D&E&F\\
B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&A\\
F&G&H&I&A&B&C&D&E\\
\end{matrix}$