# Vandermonde $V_n$ mod $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permutations, determinants

Consider the all-familiar *Vandermonde determinant* $V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of the matrix of $(i,j)$-entries $M_n(i,j)=x_j^{i-1}$ so that
$$V_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i).$$
Let's specialize the variables $x_k=k\pi_k$ where $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$ is a permutation of $n$ letters $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Assume $n>3$. I like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? $V_n(1\pi_1,2\pi_2,\dots,n\pi_n)$ is congruent to $0$ moduluo $n$ for any permutation $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$.

Comment: So the question is whether $\{k \pi_k \bmod n \mid k \in \{1,\dots,n\}\}$ can be distinct?

Comment: Let me put it this way - if a counterexample to the question exists, it must have $\pi_n=n$.

Comment: If $n$ is not prime, all the divisors $d$ appears in the product in the factor $(d+1)^2-1^2$. If $p$ is prime it is not true: for $p=2$, $V(1,4) = 4-1 = 3$ is odd. PS i am assuming @MaxAlekseyev is true, that is the only relevant permutation is $\pi_k =k$.

Comment: @AndreaMarino: My comment above is about one particular index $n$ (which is the size of the permutation), and not about the identity permutation.

Comment: Further, a counterexample must have $n$ prime. Suppose to the contrary that $n = pm$ with $p$ prime and $m > 1$, and let $A$ be the elements of $[n]$ which are divisible by $p$. There must be exactly $|A|$ values of $k$ for which $k \pi_k \in A$; if $p | k$ or $p | \pi_k$ then $k \pi_k \in A$; so either we have too many products divisible by $p$ or all of the products divisible by $p$ are divisible by $p^2$; either way, we don't get distinct products.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: this analysis needs filling some details. It would nice if this is done in the answer box because it is crucial for Max Alekseyev's response to complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per comments above, for a counterexample we have with necessity $\pi_n=n$ and prime $n$. The case $n=2$ is trivial, so I assume that $n$ is an odd prime.

The elements $U:=\{ 1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ form the unit group of $GF(n)$ and the mapping $i\mapsto i\pi_i$ has to be a permutation of $U$. Such mappings are called *complete* and [it's known](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v19i1p34/pdf/) that they do not exists whenever the group has a nontrivial, cyclic Sylow 2-subgroup. In our case, $U$ has an even order and thus a nontrivial Sylow 2-subgroup, and at the same time [all its subgroups are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59903). Hence, no complete mappings exist, providing an affirmative answer to the question.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think there was so deep math behind this question! Thanks for the elegant answer.

Comment: For a full disclosure, I have learned about the paper I cited from [this nice answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/425360) to another question.

Comment: Elementary argument: if $k\pi_k$ is a permutation of $U$, then $\prod k\pi_k$ is congruent modulo $p$ to $\prod k=(p-1)!$, that contradicts to Wilson's theorem

Comment: Thank you, Max and also Fedor.

Answer (score 3):

OP asked me to fill in the details of my comment, and in attempting to do so I realised that I claimed too much. However, a very similar argument proves a weaker result which is strong enough to support Max Alekseyev's answer (or Fedor Petrov's comment to it).

**Theorem**: if there is a counterexample, the smallest $n$ which is a counterexample is prime.

Suppose to the contrary that there is a counterexample and that the smallest counterexample is $n = ab$ with $a, b > 1$. We note that the non-vanishing of the determinant encodes the property that $k \to k \pi_k \bmod n$ is a permutation. The multiples of $a$ map to multiples of $a$; the values of $k$ for which $a | \pi_k$ also map to multiples of $a$. Therefore to preserve the bijective nature of the mapping, we require $\pi$ to map multiples of $a$ to multiples of $a$.

Considering the restriction of $\pi$ to multiples of $a$ we can define $\sigma_k = \frac{\pi_{ak}}{a}$ which must be a permutation of $[b]$. But then $k \to k \sigma_k$ is also a permutation of $[b]$, so we have a smaller counterexample, contradicting our assumption. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you, Peter.